# How to upload photo and display in folder and page using php?

Tags: php, html

I'm  trying to make where you can upload a photo and show in folder. Then when you go to the page it will show you All photo's that were uploaded. I'm using PHP and HTML for this project. 
Hopefully You understand my project by now.

This is my php code

```
<?php


  if(empty($errors)==true){
     move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,"uploads/".$file_name);
     echo "Success";
    }
    else{
       print_r($errors);
    }
 }
   ?>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main1.css"/>
 <body>
 <?php include("includes/navigation.php"); ?>   
  <form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     <input type="file" name="image" />
     <input type="submit"/>
  </form>

 </body>
</html>
```

To show on my page:

**PHP:**

```
 <?php
   $dirname = "uploads/";
   $images = glob($dirname."*.*");
  ?>

<?php
foreach($images as $image) {
echo '<img src="'.$image.'" /><br /><br />';
} 
?>
```

Help will be appreciated Thanks,

Comment: So what is the issue you are having specifically?

Comment: Not uploading. Main problem.

Comment: You have no action in your form, when you click submit nothing will happen...

Comment: You need to do something with the form data, pass it off to another file to save the photo... Also where is $errors coming from as I do not see anything about it.

Comment: @Codexer It is being passed back to the same php file, hence the blank action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
$dir = './';
$name = $_FILES['image']['name'];
$fullpath = $dir.$name;
$extension = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$tmpFilename = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$i = 1;

while(file_exists($fullpath)){
    $_FILES['image']['name'] = $tmpFilename.'('.$i.')'.$extension;
    $fullpath = $dir.$_FILES['image']['name'];
    $i++;
 }
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES('image']['tmp_name'], $fullpath);
?>
```

In your form action attribute put:

`upload_photo.php`